# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 startup problems

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

First of all, I **created and registered project** as below.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

$ mfpdev -v
8.0.0-2017080206

$ cordova -v
6.1.1

$ cord

ova create Hello com.example.helloworld HelloWorld --template cordova-template-mfp

$ cd Hello
:Hello $ cordova platform add ios@4.1.1
Adding ios project...(...no error)

:Hello $ cordova platform add android@6.1.2
Adding android project...(...no error)

:Hello $ cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 6.1.2
  ios 4.1.1
Available platforms: 
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0

:Hello $ cordova prepare

:Hello $ mfpdev app register
Verifying server configuration...
Registering to server:'ｈttp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9080' runtime:'mfp'
Updated config.xml file located at: /Users/a5566/Documents/MFP8/Hello/config.xml
Run 'cordova prepare' to propagate changes.
Registered app for platform: android
Registered app for platform: ios
```

Secondly, simply executed $ mfpdev app preview, **errors came up**:

[image]

I solved them by **adding 'mfpContextRoot' and 'applicationId'** in object 
wlInitOptions(index.js).

```
var wlInitOptions = {
    mfpContextRoot : 'mfp', 
    applicationId : 'com.example.helloworld'
};

function wlCommonInit(){
    document.getElementById('app_version').textContent = WL.Client.getAppProperty("APP_VERSION");
    document.getElementById('mobilefirst').setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
}
```

**Another error** came up:
[image]

It tells that

> WL.Client.getAppProperty is not a function.

But why? The comment said "MFP APIs should only be called within wlCommonInit() or after it has been called".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the error messages in the question directly. Also please put effort into formatting your code. And finally please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I also download cordova project from MF Console and built by Eclipse Mars(4.5.2), the application stuck like this.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By9NiE1pCErUY2VLN3ZvZ016dDg

Comment: ios-swift project from MF Console works fine.https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By9NiE1pCErUS1BXdGJ6QVpiUjQ

Comment: @MaciejJureczko Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is being fixed. Watch out this [blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/tag/Announcement/) to know the iFix details when it is rolled out.

You can then download it from [IBM FixCentral](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) or Open a PMR with IBM to obtain an iFix.

Comment: Thank you, but I just upgraded mf-cli to 8.0.0-2017091111, still the same.
$ mfpdev -v
8.0.0-2017091111

Comment: The fix is in't out yet. Watch the blog for the next 8.0 iFix. It will also describe the fixes contained within